# How can I update the values on two tables with the values from another table with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 3 tables, T1, T2, T3. I need to update the stock_status from T1 and limited from T2  with the values from stock_status and limited from T3, only where the sku are matching. 
Also the entity_id is the correspondent for product_id.

Here is an image to understand better
[image: picture]

I’m stuck at moving the values from stock_status from T3 in stock_status from T1, since I don’t have a common field directly.

For limited field, I tried.

```
UPDATE t2,t3 INNER JOIN t3 on t2.sku = t3.sku SET t2.limited = t3.limited
```

Comment: @cid what do you mean? The third tables values we're getting from an xml file, and is data from another site, from where we make our mini stocks internally, so we need the stock status from their side to be the same with stock status on our tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

```
UPDATE t1
        JOIN
    t2
        JOIN
    t3 
SET 
    t1.stock_status = t3.stock_status
WHERE
    t1.product_id = t2.entity_id
        AND t2.sku = t3.sku;
```

.

```
UPDATE t2
        JOIN
    t3 
SET 
    t2.limited = t3.limited
WHERE
    t2.sku = t3.sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use add an  inner join between t2 and t1 for update also t1.stock_status

```
  UPDATE t2,t1 
  INNER JOIN t3 on t2.sku = t3.sku 
  INNER JOIN t1 on t1.product_id = t2.entity_id
  SET t2.limited = t3.limited, 
      t1.stock_status = t3.stock_status
```

Comment: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 't3', I have this error when I try this query